# Cannot add SharePoint List to Teams tab when the list was created by exporting directly to SharePoint from Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Only 3 of the 5 lists in my SharePoint Online Team site are visible in the "Add an existing list" dialog. If I try to add either of the other 2 using a SharePoint link (the URL to the list), I get the error:

"That link did not work because you either do not have access or it is unsupported."

Those two are lists that I exported directly from Access to SharePoint, the others I either created from scratch in SharePoint or based on an uploaded Excel file. I created and am the owner of the Team site. I tried exporting the linked table for one of the lists from Access to an Excel file, then created a new list based on the Excel file. I was able to add that list to a Teams tab! That is a workaround, but it will entail a lot of work to re-do or copy over all of my formatting and views from the other list. I tried to find any settings, permission or otherwise, on the list that would fix it, but I am stumped.

Is there a way to modify this list from Access so that it can be added to a Teams tab?

Comment: Can you try to put the list URL directly in Sharepoint Page for teams tab?

Comment: That is what prompts the "That link did not work.." error! I edited to clarify. Note also that I was able to add another list from someone else in my organization using the list's URL.

Comment: This is not supported in teams